# Scout Eclipse wrap text in table cell

Tags: layout, word-wrap, eclipse-scout

I have one table in scout application where in one column I have a lot of text. (Comment column).

I would like to have text wrap into cell bounds.

I found some properties that represent that.

```
 @Override
 protected boolean getConfiguredMultilineText() {

    return true;
}
```

in Table and in column :

```
@Override
protected boolean getConfiguredTextWrap() {

    return true;
}
```

But text in column stays in one line and is not wrapped. The application is run on RAP.

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the following information:
- What UI layer do you use? (Swing, SWT, RAP)
- Which Scout Version do you use?
- What is the super type of your column?
- Did you override / what is the value of getConfiguredMultilineText() on your >Table<?

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I write in my question I use RAP UI layer and getConfiguredMultilineText() returns only true (see my question). I use Luna Scout Version: (Eclipse version 4.4.1, Scout version 4.0.1), but we will migrate to Mars very soon, so if there is a difference I would prefer Mars answer. Type of my column is AbstractStringColumn.

Answer (score 0):

With the Mars version of Eclipse Scout, this feature seems to be only available with the Swing Client:
[image: Eclipse Scout Table with Multiline Text - SWING]

With Rap, it is not working:
[image: Eclipse Scout Table with Multiline Text - RAP]

If I remember it correctly, this is a RAP/SWT limitation.

---

If the web interface matters to you, I recommend you to consider the switch to a milestone build of the Neon release:
[image: Eclipse Scout Table with Multiline Text - HTML (Neon.M3 version)]